# How to remove WooCommerce plugin dependency from Wootique theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to remove WooCommerce plugin dependency from Wootique theme? When I activate Wootique theme and click on "visit site" in wordpress it shows a message "WooCommerce must be installed".

Answer (score 1):

actually, You can't!

you must have to install "WooCommerce plugin", if you are using this Theme,
because the theme's source code is referring to WooCommerce plugin's functionality for displaying category wise products.

see [here](http://www.woothemes.com/2011/09/wootique/) for details

hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

There should be a php if ( function_exists('**woo-something**') call in the functions.php file. Look into it, that's how wordpress themes check for installed products.

You may resolve it easily or may have to do some serious editing, I can't say since I don't have the theme.